# Postgresql extensions removed on db/structure.sql when migrations runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, database-migration

I have a rails app that uses postgresql + some extensions, but every time I run `rails db:migrate` it removes the lines that enable the extensions. I have to copy and paste it manually every time.

Lines being removed on db/structure.sql:

```
-- Name: EXTENSION "postgis"; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis" WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


--
-- Name: pg_trgm; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION pg_trgm; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_trgm IS 'text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams';


--
-- Name: uuid-ossp; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" IS 'generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)';
```

My database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_HOST', 'localhost') %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_USERNAME') %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_PASSWORD') %>
  schema_search_path: public

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_production
```

Any ideas how can I fix it?

I'm using the following versions:

postgresql: 9.6

postgis: 2.3

rails: 5.0

macOS: 10.12

**UPDATE:**

I managed to find a workaround to the problem. As I'm using `schema_search_path` as public, if not defined the default option is public. Just removed this line from database.yml and it works now. Still no clues why it's happening when defining the `schema_search_path` explicitly.

Comment: you should add an answer instead of an update note and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You could generate a migration and use `enable_extension` method:

```
class AddExtensions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
   def change
     enable_extension "postgis"
     enable_extension "plpgsql"
     enable_extension "pg_trgm"
     enable_extension "uuid-ossp"
     # ...
   end
end
```

Comment: Already doing that. I managed to workaround the problem, see my update note. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue where the `database.yml` specified multiple schemas for like `schema_search_path: public, third_party`. I found the answer why the `CREATE EXTENSION` statements didn't end up in `structure.sql`.

The reason is explained in https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17157 but here is it for reference

> If the user has specified a schema_search_path and also has
>   extensions, the resulting pg_dump call generated by rake
>   db:structure:dump includes the --schema flag which means that no
>   CREATE EXTENSION statements will be created in the resulting
>   structure.sql. According to the pg_dump documentation:

Answer (score 1):

After digging thru the code for the schema dumper, I found an option that seems to help.

`ActiveRecord::Base.dump_schemas = :all`

I added this to a config/initializers/schema_dumper.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can also move all your extension to another schema like `shared_extension` and controls which database schemas will be dumped by set `config.active_record.dump_schemas = "public"`.